# Ionic 3 - Fetching array of data from Firebase then set it to input

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to fetch data from my firebase database and I want to set it to my input on my app. The app is basically an attendance app where there is a list of students then the user can check if they're absent or present or whatever.

This is the firebase structure..

[image]

this is what the page looks like..

[image]

The current code on my app..

> HTML

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Students
    </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let student of attendance">
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="student.studentName" type="text" disabled="true"></ion-input>
        <ion-select item-end [(ngModel)]="student.status">
          <ion-option value="Present">Present</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="Absent">Absent</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <button ion-button block clear (click)="addAttendance(student)"> Check!
</button>
```

> TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { StudentListService } from '../../services/students-list/students-list.service';
import { AttendanceListService } from '../../services/attendance/attendance.service';
import { Student } from '../../models/students/students.model';
import { Attendance } from '../../models/attendance/attendance.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import firebase from "firebase";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-check-attendance',
  templateUrl: 'check-attendance.html',
})

export class CheckAttendancePage {

  public attendance: any[] = [
    {
    studentName: 'name1',
    status: '',
    },
    {
    studentName: 'name2',
    status: '',
    },
  ]

  public student: any[]

  constructor(private studentsList: StudentListService, private attendanceList: AttendanceListService, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.student = this.attendance
  }

  addAttendance(student){
    console.log(student)
  }

}
```

As you can see I set the value of the attendance on the TS file, how can I set the value of the attendance.studentName to the value of the studentName from the firebase database?

**THANKS**

Comment: are you made any service for getting data from firebase database ..

Comment: did you just delete your answer? @Utpaul

Comment: The push doest work on your answer @Utpaul